# Qual a diferença entre o método string.slice() e o método string.substring()?

Tags: javascript, string

Sabemos que o método `string.slice()` e o método `string.substring()` permitem extrair uma parte de uma string e criar uma nova string como resultado (sem modificar a string original). O que diferencia um método do outro já que ambos produzem o mesmo resultado?

Comment: E aí vovô, nenhuma resposta foi boa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz a pergunta e a partir daí corri atras de uma resposta também [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como dito na pergunta** "`o método string.slice() e o método string.substring() permitem extrair uma parte de uma string e criar uma nova string como resultado (sem modificar a string original)`"

> ***Porém, uma melhoria útil em string.slice() é que a especificação de um valor de índice final relativo ao final da string principal é mais fácil.***
>
> O uso de `string.substring()` para extrair uma substring que termina antes do final da string exige alguns mecanismos, como o seguinte:
>
> ```
> string.substring(4, (string.length-2))
> ```
>
> Em vez disso, você pode atribuir um número negativo ao segundo parâmetro de `string.slice()` para informar um deslocamento a partir do final da string:
>
> ```
> string.slice(4, -2)
> ```

**Método string.slice()**

```
string.slice(indiceInicio [, indiceFim])
```

Retorna: String

- O segundo parâmetro é opcional. Se for omitido e o primeiro parâmetro não for negativo, o valor retornado será uma string a partir do deslocamento inicial até o final da string principal.
- se o primeiro parâmetro for negativo e o segundo for omitido o valor retornado será uma string a partir do final.
- Se o segundo parâmetro também for negativo e maior que o primeiro parâmetro, o valor retornado será como exemplificado a seguir:

  ```
    string="os dois parâmetros negativos";
    string.slice(-9, -2)
    do final para o inicio primeiro parâmetro (-9) resulta negativos
    segundo parãmetro (-2) retira da string resultante acima e retorna negativ
  ```
- Veja

```js
string="os dois parametros negativos";
var resultado =string.slice(-9, -2);
console.log(resultado);
```

**Abaixo você pode testar as várias situações para `string.slice()`**

```js
var mainString = "Oftalmotorrinolaringologista"
function showResults() {
 var form = document.forms[0]
 var param1 = parseInt(form.param1.options[form.param1.selectedIndex].value)
 var param2 = parseInt(form.param2.options[form.param2.selectedIndex].value)
 if (!param2) {
  form.result1.value = mainString.slice(param1)
 } else {
  form.result1.value = mainString.slice(param1, param2)
 }
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
<form>
<tr><th>Metodo String</th><th>Metodo Parametros</th><th>Resultado</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>string.substring()</td><td>
(&nbsp;<select name="param1" onChange="showResults()">
 <option value=0>0
 <option value=1>1
 <option value=2>2
 <option value=3>3
 <option value=5>5
 <option value=10>10
 <option value=30>30
 <option value=-1>-1
 <option value=-3>-3
 <option value=-5>-5
 <option value=-10>-10
</select>,
<select name="param2" onChange="showResults()">
    <option>(Não)
    <option value=1>1
    <option value=3>3
    <option value=5>5
    <option value=10>10
    <option value=30>30
    <option value=-1>-1
    <option value=-3>-3
    <option value=-5>-5
    <option value=-10>-10
</select>&nbsp;) </td>
<td><input type="text" name="result1" value="Oftalmotorrinolaringologista" size=25></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

**Método string.substring()**

```
string.substring(indiceA, indiceB)
```

Retorna: String de caracteres entre os valores de índice indiceA e indiceB

- Os parâmetro desse método são os valores de índice inicial e final da string principal, da qual o trecho deve ser retirado. Um item importante a observar é que o trecho chega até ele, mas não inclui o caractere apontado pelo valor de índice mais alto.
- Não faz diferença qual valor de índice nos parâmetros é maior do que o outro: o método inicia o trecho a partir do menor valor e continua para (mas não inclui) o valor mais alto. Se os dois valores forem iguais, o método retorna uma string vazia; e se você omitir o segundo parâmetro, o final da string é considerado como ponto final.

**Abaixo você pode testar as várias situações para `string.substring()`**

```js
var mainString = "Oftalmotorrinolaringologista"
function showResults() {
 var form = document.forms[0]
 var param1 = parseInt(form.param1.options[form.param1.selectedIndex].value)
 var param2 = parseInt(form.param2.options[form.param2.selectedIndex].value)
 if (!param2) {
  form.result1.value = mainString.substring(param1)
 } else {
  form.result1.value = mainString.substring(param1, param2)
 }
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
<form>
<tr><th>Metodo String</th><th>Metodo Parametros</th><th>Resultado</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>string.substring()</td><td>
(&nbsp;<select name="param1" onChange="showResults()">
 <option value=0>0
 <option value=1>1
 <option value=2>2
 <option value=3>3
 <option value=5>5
 <option value=10>10
 <option value=30>30
</select>,
<select name="param2" onChange="showResults()">
    <option>(Não)
    <option value=1>1
    <option value=3>3
    <option value=5>5
    <option value=10>10
    <option value=30>30
    <option value=-1>-1
    <option value=-5>-5
    <option value=-10>-10
</select>&nbsp;) </td>
<td><input type="text" name="result1" value="Oftalmotorrinolaringologista" size=25></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`slice()` funciona como `substring()` com alguns comportamentos diferentes.

**Sintaxes**

string.slice(start, stop);
string.substring(start, stop);

**O que eles têm em comum:**

Se start for igual a stop: retorna uma string vazia

Se stop for omitido: extrai caracteres para o final da string

Se um dos argumentos for maior que o comprimento da string, o comprimento da string será usado no lugar.

**Distinções de [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):**

Se start > stop, então a substring irá trocar esses 2 argumentos.
Se um dos argumentos for negativo ou for NaN, será tratado como se fosse 0.

**Distinções de [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):**

Se start > stop, slice() NÃO irá trocar os 2 argumentos.
Se start for negativo: define char no final da string, exatamente como substr() no Firefox. Esse comportamento é observado no Firefox e no IE.
Se stop for negativo: define stop para: string.length - Math.abs(stop) (valor original), exceto limitado a 0 (portanto, Math.max (0, string.length + stop)) conforme coberto na especificação ECMA .

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring)